# Will a slightly differently shaped torus make this guess about plane sections of a torus true?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, conformal-geometry, elliptic-functions

[Jacobi's elliptic functions and plane sections of a torus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260202/jacobis-elliptic-functions-and-plane-sections-of-a-torus/260781#260781)

After Greg Egan posted an excellent answer to a question of mine, which I accepted, I posted my own answer, linked above. The question hazarded a conjecture that is trivially true in two trivial cases and whose truth in another case follows from something proved in the 1890s, but only approximately true more generally.

My present question is the one with which I ended the answer links above: If, instead of revolving a circle about a line, getting a standard embedded torus, one revolves some slightly different simple closed curve about that line, does the conjecture become true? And if so, can anything of interest be said about that curve beyond just computing it numerically?

**To keep this self-contained, here is that earlier question:**

In $\mathbb R^3$ with Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z),$ revolve the circle $(x-\sqrt 2)^2+z^2 =1,\  y=0$ about the $z$-axis.

This yields a torus embedded in $3$-space that is conformally equivalent to the flat torus $(\mathbb R/(2\pi))^2,$ via a mapping that takes $(x,y,z)=(1+\sqrt 2,0,0)$ to $(0,0)$ and $(x,z) = (-1-\sqrt 2,0, 0)$ to $(0,\pi),$ and $(-1+\sqrt 2,0,0)$ to $(\pi,0)$ and $(1-\sqrt 2,0,0)$ to $(\pi,\pi).$

One of Jacobi's elliptic functions gives us a $2$-to-$1$ mapping from the flat torus into $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ that takes $(0,0)$ to $0$ and $(0,\pi)$ to $\infty.$

Then the inverse of the stereographic projection takes $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ while taking $0$ to $(1,0,0)$ and $\infty$ to $(-1,0,0).$

The composition of mappings takes the embedded torus to the sphere.

**Fact 1:** This composition of mappings takes the largest and the smallest of the four $x$-intercepts of the torus respectively to the largest and smallest of the two $x$-intercepts of the sphere.

**Fact 2:** This composition of mappings is conformal except at four points on the torus (corresponding to points at which the derivative of Jacobi's function is $0$).

(Unless I got some of the nitpicking details wrong about which points map to which) I believe I have reason to suspect the following really startling proposition:

> The intersection of this sphere with each plane containing the $x$-axis is the image under this composition of mappings of the intersection of the torus with the **same** plane.

So I'm wondering:

- Is this true?
- Is it known?
- Can it be proved by using some known fact about Jacobi's function and maybe some elbow grease?

**APPENDIX:** The inverse of the conformal mapping from the embedded torus to the flat torus is this:
\begin{align}
\text{For }\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R/(2\pi), \\[4pt]
x & = \cos\beta/(\sqrt2-\cos\alpha) \\[4pt]
y & = \sin\beta/(\sqrt2-\cos\alpha) \\[4pt]
z & = \sin\alpha/(\sqrt2-\cos\alpha) \longleftarrow \text{same denominator in all three coordinates}
\end{align}

**POSTSCRIPT:** If I'm not mistaken, I've reduced this to the following.

You have a doubly periodic holomorphic function with periods $2\pi$ and $2\pi i$ that takes $0$ and $\pi + i\pi$ to $0$ and takes $\pi$ and $i\pi$ to $\infty.$

Now look at the inverse-images of straight lines through $0$ corresponding to arguments (i.e. angles from the real axis) between $0$ and $45^\circ$. Those inverse-images should be graphs of functions of the form $y=\arcsin(c\sin(x))$ where $x$ and $y$ are respectively the real and imaginary parts.

Is that a known proposition about Jacobi's functions?